# If each two vectors in $S$ are linearly independent then is $S$ linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a infinite dimensional vector space over the field $K$.

Let $S \subset V$ be a subset of $V$ such that
$$
\forall s, z \in S : a \cdot s + b \cdot z = 0 \Rightarrow a=b=0
$$
where $a,b \in K$

Is it true that $S$ is linearly independent ?
(linearly independent i mean for a finite number of distinct vectors in $S$)

Comment: Try $K=\mathbb{R}$, $V=\mathbb{R}[x]$, $A(x)=1$, $B(x)=x$ and $C(x)=1+x$, $S=\{A,B,C\}$

Comment: It seems to work only if $S$ is a vector space. In this case you can prove it with induction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is already wrong in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Take $S$ to be the system
$$(v_1,v_2,v_3) := \left( \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 2\\1\end{pmatrix} \right).$$

Now any two vectors of $S$ are linearly independent, but clearly $S$ is not since $v_1 + v_2 = v_3$.

If you want the vector space to be infinite dimensional, just append zeros to each vector and pretend they are elements of $l^\infty$. Or use polynomials as in one of the comments to your question.

Comment: I had a very similar counter example thought up. Great answer!

Comment: @Elvorfirilmathredia thanks for this astute counter example